# A Question About Little-O Notation

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification, definition

> How could the following be interpreted:
>   $$ h(t)=\dfrac{1+o(1)}{(2 \pi)^{3/2}\sqrt{t}} \; \; \; \text{as} \; t\downarrow0 \tag{1} $$
>   Where $o(1)$ is the little-o notation.

From my understanding, if we say that $$f(x)=o(g(x)) \; \; \text{as} \; t \downarrow 0$$ then this means that $$\dfrac{f(x)}{g(x)} \to 0 \; \; \text{as} \; t\downarrow0$$
Now from (1) am I allowed to say that 
$$ (2 \pi)^{3/2}\sqrt{t}\cdot h(t) -1 =o(1) \; \; \text{as} \; t\downarrow 0 \tag{2}$$
And then by applying the definition of little-o notation to (2), we see that 
$$ (2 \pi)^{3/2}\sqrt{t}\cdot h(t) -1 \to 0 \; \; \text{as} \; t \downarrow 0 $$

Or should I interpret (1) in a different way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you said is correct, and you can also think of it as saying there exists $f$ in $o(1)$ as $t\to0$ such that

$$h(t) = \frac{1+f(t)}{(2\pi)^{3/2}\sqrt{t}}$$

Answer (score 2):

I would write
$h(t)=\dfrac{1+o(1)}{(2 \pi)^{3/2}\sqrt{t}}
$
as
$h(t)=\dfrac{1}{(2 \pi)^{3/2}\sqrt{t}}
+o(\dfrac1{\sqrt{t}})
$
so that
$h(t)-\dfrac{1}{(2 \pi)^{3/2}\sqrt{t}}
=o(\dfrac1{\sqrt{t}})
$
or
$\sqrt{t}(h(t)-\dfrac{1}{(2 \pi)^{3/2}\sqrt{t}})
\to 0
$
or
$\sqrt{t}h(t)-\dfrac{1}{(2 \pi)^{3/2}}
\to 0
$
or
$\sqrt{t}h(t)\to\dfrac{1}{(2 \pi)^{3/2}}
$.

Comment: Why does $$\dfrac{1+o(1)}{(2 \pi)^{3/2}\sqrt{t}} =\dfrac{1}{(2 \pi)^{3/2}\sqrt{t}}
+o(\dfrac1{\sqrt{t}})$$

Comment: Because you split the added terms and big-oh and little-oh allow you to ignore constant multipliers.